# Accessibilty -Focus is lost when route changed in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

Navigating between Components Focus is getting lost.i have forcefully set the focus to a menu button but once the router navigation is changed then also the focus is getting lost. Is there a fix to reset the focus on route changes?

These attributes also doesn't work **(autofocus, setfocus ,cdkfocusinitial)**...

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution Initially blur the Element and set the focus for the same element ...working fine !!!!!!!!!

```
let blurElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('menubutton')[0] as HTMLElement;
blurElement.blur();

setTimeout(function(){
  let focusElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('menubutton')[0] as HTMLElement;
  focusElement.focus();
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the autofocus will not work 
ref http://www.angulartutorial.net/2018/03/angular-autofocus-for-input-box-angular.html

Comment: thanks @ketan vaidya , for the link, ...do u have another approach to solve this issue ???

Comment: In ngAfterViewInIt you can set it by using js or Jquery so it will autofocus after your view has been initialised

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a completely solved problem, but there are some better and worse ways to handle it. I think you will have to call `focus()` on something after rendering the newly routed content, although there have been various attempts to make this happen automatically which (as others have pointed out) don't really work properly.

The real question is **what to focus on**. This can be easy or challenging depending on what you have at the top of your pages.

Be sure to read [this (longish) article](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-07-11-user-testing-accessible-client-routing/) about handling focus when changing route in single-page apps. It's the best empirical study of the topic to date, with some viable suggestions.